# Hdr photo for overlaying other photos

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, gamma, hdr

I wanted to know if it is possible starting from some photos by appropriately modifying the gamma values ​​to perform an overlap and tone mapping and extract a hdr photo, I found some code on the internet but I want the exposure values ​​which I do not have.
If it were possible, the code would be welcome.

Comment: I do not understand. You have to start with an HDR image and then do tone mapping on it to generate something in a normal non-HDR range of tones. Are you asking to create an HDR image from a non-HDR, normal range image? Please clarify what you mean by "extract" an HDR image.

Comment: @fmw42 I think he means he wants to take several standard dynamic range pictures to produce HDR picture, but he wants to modify gamma value instead of exposure. In that case, modifying gamma value might help you get more than 8-bit luminosity depth, but areas with too much or too little exposure (white and black pixels) won't improve. Most cameras allow you to access raw image formats, on which you should do the tone mapping instead.

Comment: `@zteffi` Agreed